# Pandas Combine 2 dataframes based on Id's

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes as shown

```
df1 = 
drugid          v1 v2 v3                            
1             a   b   c                    
3             g  d   s            
5             n  n  n
```

```
df2 = 
trialID        drugid             v4    v5   v6           
10             [1,3,5]            k       k    k                                               
20              [3,5]             k1     k2    k3                    
30              [5,1]             h       g    s
```

I would like to get the resultant dataframe as:

```
df_result = 
trial_id     drug_id     v4   v5   v6   v1   v2   v3
10             1          k    k    k   a     b    c
10             3          k    k    k   g     d    s
10             5          k    k    k   n     n    n
20             3          k1   k2   k3  g     d    s
20             5
30             5
30             1
```

I used for loop + pd.concat to merge the 2 rows and again pd.concat to put them in a combined_df, to create this combined one to many dataframe, But that is taking forever to get the answer. I was wondering if there was any simpler solution to this. Something that is a little faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode `df2` on "drugid" so each drug ID is in its own row, then merge the DataFrames on "drugid".

```
df2 = df2.explode('drugid')
result = df2.merge(df1, on='drugid', how='left')
```

Comment: df.explode worked like a charm! Thank you very much :) You are awesome!